# AWS Lambda to execute EMR Studio Notebook (PySpark) on EMR

Tags: pyspark, aws-lambda, automation, amazon-emr, aws-emr-studio

Is there a Lambda function that can initiate the execution of an EMR Studio notebook containing a PySpark script (.py) performing basic operations such as reading from and writing to an S3 bucket on an EMR cluster?

I tried  the below 2 functions

1. response = emr_client.start_notebook_execution(EditorId=notebook_id,RelativePath='test_pyspark.py',ExecutionEngine={'Id': cluster_id},ServiceRole='EMR_Notebooks_DefaultRole')
2. steps = [
   {
   'Name': 'Test_Space',
   'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',  # Define action on failure
   'HadoopJarStep': {
   'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
   'Args': [
   'spark-submit',
   '--deploy-mode', 'cluster',
   '--master', 'yarn',
   's3://aws-emr-resources-us-east-1/test_pyspark.py'
   ]
   }
   }
   ]
   and I expected to run the script and save results in S3. But no results were saved in S3.

Comment: Please provide some more details that may be helpful.  For example, when you check the EMR page, do you see any errors.  ? What's  in the logs for the lambda execution and emr run

Comment: Error message in EMR step: 24/02 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0at org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner.main(PythonRunner.scala) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.1-amzn-0.jar:3.41amznsun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.02 atava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~ ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 13, (reason: User class threw exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0  org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.AppMaster$$anon$2.run(AppMaster.scala:760)